# ASP.NET Core MVC: Order Navigation Property is Null When Creating Item, Resulting in Invalid ModelState

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC application, and I have a situation where I'm trying to create an Item that's associated with an Order. I'm using a dropdown list to select the OrderID, which is working fine, but I'm encountering an issue where the Order navigation property of the Item is always null, and this is causing the ModelState to be invalid.

Here's a simplified version of my Item model:

```
public class Item
 {
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int QuantityInStock { get; set; }

    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
 }
```

I'm using the _ordersService to fetch the valid OrderID values in the GET action for creating an Item. In the POST action, I use the selected OrderID to associate the Item with the Order.

Here are my Create actions:

```
// GET: Items/Create
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var itemsWithOrders = _ordersService.GetAllOrders();
    var orderIDs = itemsWithOrders.Select(item => new
    {
        item.OrderID,
    }).ToList();
    ViewBag.OrderIDList = new SelectList(orderIDs, "OrderID", "OrderID");
    return View();
}

// POST: Items/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult Create([Bind("ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID")] Item item)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _itemsService.CreateItem(item);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    // Additional code to handle ModelState errors

    return View(item);
}
```

he issue is that when I create an Item, the Order navigation property remains null, and this results in ModelState being invalid. I suspect that the issue might be related to how I'm associating the Item with the Order.

How can I ensure that the Order navigation property is correctly populated when creating an Item? What might be causing it to be null, and how can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: all you need is the OrderId, as that's the foreign key... your model should be like  [ForeignKey("OrderID")]
        public virtual  Order Order { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your codes, you directly use the data model(Item) inside view, since the Item contains the Order property which the client will not return, the model validation will always false due to the Order is always null.

One possible solution is using Modlestate.Remove method to remove the order validation, like below:

```
ModelState.Remove("Order");
```

But I don't suggest you do that, I suggest you could create a new viewmodel which contains `"ItemName,Price,QuantityInStock,OrderID"` to handle the view data, and then using some map serivce to map the viewmodel with the datamodel.

Always keep in mind that exposing data models directly to the view might lead to security risks (such as mass assignment vulnerability) or unintended data exposure. Always use a ViewModel or DTO to expose only the needed data to the view or client.